# Installed vim colorscheme is not be found at startup, but it can be set once vim is loaded

Tags: vim, colors, vim-plugin

I have installed with Vundle this [github colours theme](https://github.com/cormacrelf/vim-colors-github). I installed is with `:VundleInstall` and it seems to work just fine. The directory `~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-github` is there. Indeed, I can switch the color scheme with `colorscheme github`.

Next, I have added the following lines to `~/.vimrc` to make this change permanent:

```
" github colors
let g:github_colors_soft = 1 
Plugin 'cormacrelf/vim-colors-github'
colorscheme github
```

But this raises the error "E185: colorscheme «github» not found".

It just doesn't work during the loading of vim!? What's going on here? I guess there is something that hasn't been set *yet* at the time of calling the change in the colorscheme. How could I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the call to `vundle#end()` at the end of your plug-in configuration. See [the quick start guide](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) which shows an example of defining plug-ins in your vimrc:

```
call vundle#begin()
Plugin ...
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

In your case, adding those lines around your `Plugin` definition will most likely fix the issue:

```
" load plugins
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'cormacrelf/vim-colors-github'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" github colors
let g:github_colors_soft = 1 
colorscheme github
```

Also note that Vundle hasn't really been very thoroughly maintained. While there's nothing wrong with it, [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) is a compatible alternative (works the same way, uses similar configuration and similar commands) which is well maintained and offers improvements in terms of performance and features. I'd definitely recommend switching to vim-plug, particularly if you're getting started with a Vim plug-in manager of this style.

Answer (score 1):

Color schemes are searched along `'runtimepath'` and `'packpath'`. Therefore they will only be found on startup if you install plugins with respect to `:h packages` (i.e. under `'packpath'`), not under arbitrary `~/.vim/bundle`.

As for Vundle and such you are expected to manually set up `'runtimepath'`, so that it includes all plugins *before* executing `:colorscheme`. For Vundle it is done by calling `vundle#end()`.